# Boost Note won't sync with GNOME Online Accounts

Tags: nautilus, sync, online-accounts, alternative

I'm trying to sync my notes on Boostnote with Google Drive automatically using GNOME Online Accounts. I've connected my Drive folder, but when I create a storage location in that folder, Boostnote just doesn't want to create a folder in that location. As someone who is brand-new to Linux, what is going on here? Why can I not utilize the connection to create a storage location in Boostnote? I'm assuming it's related to what Chris Hoffman writes on How-To Geek [How to Use Google Drive on Linux](https://www.howtogeek.com/196635/an-official-google-drive-for-linux-is-here-sort-of-maybe-this-is-all-well-ever-get/):

> ...your files won’t actually “sync” to your desktop, which means you won’t get an entirely offline copy. It’s just a convenient way to manage, open, and modify files without using your web browser.

Does anyone have any recommendations for alternatives? (Either in cloud storage or tools for sync--I found ExpanDrive, for example, but I don't know if I trust it, and either way it costs a bloody fortune...)